# Dividing and Multiplying Pixel Values

Tags: python, image-processing, pixel

Using Python code, I was asked to load an image into a variable I, then set a variable n=5. Then using ip.immultiply() divide all the pixel values in I by n, and store the result in a new variable J. Again, using ip.immultiply() multiply all the pixel values in J by n and store the result in a variable K. Then we want to compare the images I and K. However we are asked to increase the value of n. And explain why an image using the higher value of n will be more distorted.

I had no problem writing my code. I was able to acquire the two correct and different images. I set n=15 and the image was much more distortored. My question is why when dividing by a larger value of n then multiplying by the same larger value of n will it give you a more distorted image. As well as why does dividing and multiplying pixel values distort an image.

Comment: One word: [Posterization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Posterization)

Comment: I thought this was repeated use of the median filter that caused this

Comment: Anything that reduces the number of colors in an image will cause posterization. Median filter can certainly do it, but in your case it would be the loss of precision caused by the divide and subsequent conversion of the result to int.

Comment: Ok, so the reason is because when you divide by a larger number you are dividing the pixel. Clipping doesn't happen because the values of the pixels are 1/15 of the original value in the first step. so  because we work with an array of integers, the odd pixel values will be off by 1 in the final result, after halving and doubling. Is this because the dividing step rounds the odd pixel values to the nearest integer.
or am I completely off with my reasoning

Comment: Sounds like you get it. Halving and doubling is the *best* case, dividing by 15 causes your original 255 color possibilities to narrow to 17.

Comment: sorry I didn't mean halving and doubling I meant dividing the original image by 1/15 and then multiplying the new image by 15 to give another image say K. however by dividing by 15 means there are only 17 colours available so the image is not going to be as good quality but I still don't really get what multiplying my 15 will do

Comment: Dividing by 15 will leave the image much darker because the range will only be 0-16 instead of 0-255. Multiplying will restore the lightness but leave holes, for example the values 1-14 won't be used.

Comment: why will the values 1-14 not be used?

Comment: `all((i//15) * 15 == 0 for i in range(1,15)) == True`. Multiplying an integer by 15 can never create a result between 1 and 14. The same is true for the range 16-29, 31-44, etc.

Comment: If you divide all the values by 15, you will get an integer less than or equal to 16, i.e.,0, 1, 2, 3.. 16. Now let's multiply each of those values by 15. We get 0*15=0, 1*15=15, 2*15=30. Notice how 1..14 are missing, and 16-29 and so on.